# Dimension of a phase space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$\dot x=v(t,x).$
Is the phase space dimension two here? Cuz $x$ and $t$, both are required to determine $\dot x$, all of which then specify the state of the system uniquely.

Now consider $\dot x=v(x).$
Is the dimension one here? Cuz we only need to specify $x$ for the system to know its state uniquely. (It’s invariant under $t$-translations.)

Comment: @Gae.S. Sorry, dunno about these things...

Comment: Can you just verify if my conclusion and reasoning are correct?